# Is this pollen?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, species-identification

The small round "pockets/buns" in the image. I am almost sure it is, but maybe someone knows more. Sample comes from ([50.156992, 12.532546](https://www.google.com/maps/place/50%C2%B009'25.2%22N+12%C2%B031'57.2%22E/@50.1159762,12.1986519,9.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d50.156992!4d12.532546)) (Google coordinates). It is a re-cultivated tailing in the Czech Republic. In the specific area we find birch trees and fir trees.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What area is that? Can you give geographic coordinates or something?

Comment: Yes. Google coordinates: 50.156992, 12.532546 . It is a re-cultivated tailing in the Czech Republic.

Comment: Looks like pollen to me, and I've spent a lot of time looking at pollen